# How do I go back to the previous tab only when I hit back or click on the link the brings me back to the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

I have a page. The page has tabs. One of the tabs (lets call it Tab 4) has links that opens up other pages (and takes you away from the page with the tabs). This secondary page has a link on it then when clicked brings you back to the tabbed page on the tab you last left off on (Tab 4). Obviously if you hit the back button it does this also. The issue is, is that each time you initialize the page (i.e. visit the page for the first time in the day, or visit the page later on (without hitting back or "previous page" link, I end up remaining on the last tab I was on when I last visited the page (Tab 4). Can someone tell me what to add and where so that when I type the URL in at a later time it will then default me back to Tab 1 (but will go to Tab 4 if I hit back or the previous page link).

Basically I want the state to refresh if I visit the page at a later time but not to refresh if I hit back or "click to previous page". How would I set an expiry date to the local storage (i.e. for the only instance they are on the connecting page) Here is the code.

```
<script>
jQuery('#lmd_create_tabs > ul li').click(function(e) {
    var i = jQuery(this).prevAll().length;
    localStorage.activeTab = i;
});

jQuery(function() {
    var myActiveTab
        if (typeof localStorage.activeTab !== 'undefined') {
            myActiveTab = localStorage.activeTab;
        }
    jQuery('#lmd_create_tabs > ul > li:eq('+myActiveTab+')').trigger('click');
});

jQuery(function() {

    // Capture click event
    jQuery('#lmd_create_tabs > ul li').click(function(e) {
        var i = jQuery(this).prevAll().length;
        localStorage.activeTab = i;
    });

    var myActiveTab = 0;

    if (typeof localStorage.activeTab !== 'undefined') {
        myActiveTab = localStorage.activeTab;
    }

    jQuery('#lmd_create_tabs > ul > li:eq('+myActiveTab+')').trigger('click');
});
</script>
```

Comment: I only want it to save to the local storage when hitting back or the link, but to erase the local storage if I go to the page at a later date. Someone mnentioned something about document.referrer. Meaning when the URL changes and go back (by clicking the back button or previous page hyperlink) it brings to be to the last tab left off, but when I visit the page by typing the URL in it brings to Tab 1

Comment: Can you give us a jsfiddle with an example?

Comment: Unfortunately the page I am referring to is currently in staging the company firewall and is unable to. I go to the page i.e. www.sony.com/laser it starts me off on the Technology Overview tab. I click on another tab it brings to a content that has links to another page. I want to be able to hit back and proceed back to that "another tab." But when I type www.sony.com/laser in again or navigate my way back to the page it needs to be bring me back to the Technology Overview tab. Unfortunately I am very beginner in JS and the code above was given to me and the person is now unable to help again.